# Disable triggers in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

We have created a table with a trigger that updates a ModifiedDate field in it each time there is an UPDATE/INSERT. For a particular transaction in our app, though, we would like to temporally disable this trigger.

Would it be possible to do this directly from LINQ? 
(Directly, not calling a stored procedure)

Comment: warning, warning! disabling a trigger WILL affect any other UPDATEs that run at the same time! this (disable trigger) sounds like a hack to a bad design, so I'll offer up a crappy hack to solve this.  update the date in the application to something like 1/1/1900, then in your trigger realize this bogus date, ignore the standard date update logic and set it back to the DELETED.yourDateColumn, thus restoring your date.

Comment: Arg. You are right. I've never had a similar problem before and I hadn't noticed that the solutions using SQL disabled the triggers for the table and not for the scope of the transaction.


It indeed intended to be a fast hack to solve a change in requirements at the end of a project (we now need to perform a maintenance task in the records of the DB, but being an internal process the customer doesn't want the "ModifiedDate" field to change).

I'm not a big fan of hacks, though, and you have convinced me. We'll remove the triggers altogether and update the field only when needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using the generated code. You could hook into a stored procedure, but that may involve extra work.

For "last updated" data, it is possible to hook into the `DataContext`'s change-set that is obtained during the `SubmitChanges` method - so it is possible set properties (perhaps based on an interface) for the rows that are being submitted for `UPDATE`.

I have a similar issue, where my audit triggers behave differently based on which columns are part of the `UPDATE` statement (via `UPDATE(ColumnName)` in the trigger), so in a similar question I needed to hack the data-context to [always consider a specific column dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560513/can-you-convince-a-datacontext-to-treat-a-column-as-always-dirty). That may have *some* cross-over.

But no: I don't think you can disable the triggers completely.

Comment: Oh well, I imagined the answer, but it would have been nice if there had been a way! :)