# Using Linq to Sql, does not update, but does not throw exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Running .net 2008, asp.net, Linq to sql, sql server 2008 express

```
Foo f = db.Foo.First(x => x.ID == id);
f.IsValid = true;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I have a very basic table, which has several fields, and no FK constraints.  None of the data saves when I call .SubmitChanges(), but no error is thrown.  Any ideas?

Not using any explicit transaction scope, fields are not autogenerated, and no triggers on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tyop aside, the first thing to try is setting `db.Log = Console.Out;` to see if any TSQL is issues (or better: run a SQL trace). If nothing is getting *sent* then maybe `IsValid` was *already* true - it won't re-save such changes unless it has to ([unless you force it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560513/can-you-convince-a-datacontext-to-treat-a-column-as-always-dirty)).

Less likely, you could perhaps have accidentally turning off object-tracking (`db.ObjectTrackingEnabled`).

Other common mistakes include:

- not calling `Complete()` when using `TransactionScope` (if you *are* using `TransactionScope`)
- with database *files* (rather than a separate server), checking in the original file (in the solution) rather than in the build output (typically /bin/debug or /bin/release).

I'm also *assuming* that `IsValid` is actually a db-mapped property (they don't have to be)

Comment: Marking this as the solution, since it led me to the solution.

Comment: @Marc this issue can also be caused by the table not having a PK defined.  In this case LINQ to SQL will silently ignore changes.

Comment: And for those who using Entity Framework 6 `db.Database.Log = Console.Write`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `IsValid` on `f` and not on `x`.

```
Foo f = db.Foo.First(x => x.ID == id); 
f.IsValid = true; 
db.SubmitChanges();
```

And remember to call `Complete` on your `TransactionScope` if you are using one.

Comment: that was a typo.  x.IsValid wouldn't compile, much less not throw an exception ;)  Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 2):

Is IsValid marked as an AutoGenerated field in the designer?  If so, no changes that you make will be propagated back to the server.  Also, is it possible that you have a DB trigger that may be running on update, instead of say on insert, that is setting it to a default value of 0 (false)?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the primary key had been dropped from the DB since the last time I was working with this application.  When I regenerated the .dbml recently it generated with no primary key.  Adding that back in has fixed the problem.