# if no data has changed, the behavior stored procedure won't execute

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a `.dbml` with one table and that table have associated behavior for update/delete/insert which are stored procedures.

If I query a row and I'm not modifying it or I set the same value that was there and I call `datacontext.save()`, it won't execute the stored procedure.

Is there a way to know that it won't be executed or force it?

Comment: If nothing changed - ***why*** would you even want to execute that stored procedure??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the stored procedure to execute by tricking linq2sql to think that a column is always 'dirty'. The answer to this question may help:

[Can you convince a DataContext to treat a column as always dirty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560513/can-you-convince-a-datacontext-to-treat-a-column-as-always-dirty/1563751#1563751)